# How do I change a constant based on the build target in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I need to use one of two different URLs depending on the build target.
If I build on the simulator I need to use URLA, on a device URLB.

In Objective C, I used Preprocessor Macros in the .pch file for Debug mode (one for iOS simulator SDK, another for iOS SDK).
But now, I use Xcode 6 and I develop in Swift.

How can I change a constant in swift based on the build target?

Comment: The class prefix mentioned in that link is referring to the letters at the beginning of identifiers - e.g. the NS in NSString; AF in the AFNetworking library, etc. Nothing to do with precompiled headers, which are irrelevant to your actual problem.

Comment: It might be easiest (possibly even necessary) to do it in the bridging header.

Comment: I found another solution, in Builds Settings / Swift Compiler - Custom Flags / Other Swift Flags / Debug, I add -DSimulator for "Any iOS Simulator SDK", and -DDevice for "Any iOS SDK". I create Constants.swift with `#if Device ... #endif'. And it works.